# Can't use asyncio with pywin32 to create a Windows Service

Tags: python, windows-services, python-asyncio, pywin32

I'm using pywin32 to create a Windows Service.

Problem is whenever I call `asyncio` functions like `asyncio.run()`, `asyncio.ensure_future()`, `asyncio.get_event_loop()` or `asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()` I get an `ValueError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread`.

Python version: 3.8.8

Executed as: `python test.py install` and then `python test.py start`. Error is found in `C:/xxx/errorLogs2.txt`

Code:

```
import socket

import win32serviceutil

import servicemanager
import win32event
import win32service
import asyncio

class Test(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'testService'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'Test Service'
    _svc_description_ = 'Test Service Description'

    @classmethod
    def parse_command_line(cls):
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(cls)

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        try:
            l = asyncio.get_event_loop() # Fails here
            servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                                servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                                (self._svc_name_, ''))
        except Exception as e:
            with open('C:/xxx/errorLogs2.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write(str(e) + '\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test.parse_command_line()
```